# randomly change columns in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have the following view

```
sqms_question_id (int), 
question (text), 
sqms_answer_1 (text), 
correct_id_1, 
sqms_answer_2 (text), 
correct_id_2 (T/F), 
sqms_answer_3(text), 
correct_id_3 (T/F)
```

I now need to mix the answer randomly (because answer 1 is always true). I would create another view based on the first view since i cannot change the first one

Any idea I can do this in mysql directly?

Ok. sample data -

sqms_question_id (int), question (text), sqms_answer_1 (text), correct_id_1, sqms_answer_2 (text), correct_id_2 (T/F), sqms_answer_3(text), correct_id_3 (T/F)

1, "What is ?", "answer1A",TRUE,"answer1B",TRUE,"answer1C",FALSE

2, "What is ?", "answer2A",TRUE,"answer2B",TRUE,"answer2C",TRUE

3, "What is ?", "answer3A",TRUE,"answer3B",FALSE,"answer3C",FALSE

4, "What is ?", "answer4A",TRUE,"answer4B",FALSE,"answer4C",TRUE

Output (randomly)

1, "What is ?", "answer1C",FALSE,"answer1B",TRUE,"answer1A",TRUE,

2, "What is ?", "answer2B",TRUE,"answer2A",TRUE,"answer2C",TRUE

3, "What is ?", "answer3A",TRUE,"answer3B",FALSE,"answer3C",FALSE

4, "What is ?", "answer4C",TRUE,"answer4B",FALSE,"answer4A",TRUE,

Hope this example made it more clear - in this example row 3 was not changed ....

Comment: Yep... after re-reading 3 times I still don't understand what you're trying to do.  Sample data expected results would help.

Comment: @robkuhlig Why do you not randomize the answers in your programming language where you have read the question from the database?

Comment: I think you want to randomize the order of the columns. and it is never possible to randomize the columns Only rows can be randomize